# Can we assign the address of 2D integer array in double pointer of integer type?How is it possible?

Tags: c++

////Main.cpp////////////

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int a[2][2]={1,2,3,4};
    int **ptr=&a;   


    cout << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

When above code is compiled ,it gives the following errors

```
[Error] cannot convert 'int (*)[2][2]' to 'int**' in initialization
```

Comment: "Can we...?" Did you [attempt to compile it](https://ideone.com/1Zct92)? Is your question about the compiler error? If so, please post the error and make your question more explicit.

Comment: When I compile your program, I'm getting `8:16: error: cannot convert ‘int (*)[2][2]’ to ‘int**’ in initialization int **ptr=&a;`. It seems to be a XY Problem. Would you like to explain what you are actually trying to do? Are you asking "it it possible to perform pointer arithmetics on a two dimensional array?"

Comment: The error is correct.  You cannot convert the one thing into the other thing.  They are incompatible.

Comment: So ,whats the right way?

Comment: @user20913 -- "So, what's the right way?" -- that depends on what you're trying to do. What are you trying to do?

Comment: `int (*ptr)[2] = a;` may do  what you want, depending on what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: after assigning this 2D array to pointer,I want the pointer to access all elements of array.

Comment: I would recommend to look around for articles on why "pointers to pointer" are not 2D arrays. They should also give a more in-depth explanation on how "pointer to 1D array" can be used to pass around 2D arrays, in the same way that a "pointer to value" can be used to pass around 1D arrays.

Comment: *Why* do you want a pointer to access all elements of the array? What benefit do you hope to achieve? (Taking the address of an array usually does not help accomplish a real goal.)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is bad form but what you need is reinterpret_cast

```
  int **ptr=reinterpret_cast<int **>(a);
```

Comment: Here is a car-analogy for your solution: "You may fix your brakes by removing the brake warning light." You are just telling the compiler to ignore the broken code. It won't actually fix anything.

Comment: That's good and so true.

Comment: Bad form ? Um... you're essentially saying lie to the compiler, a tool that only has two jobs: (1) turn your code into machine instructions, and (2) tell you by warning or error if you're doing something stupid. Fooling the latter to achieve the former is hardly every helpful, and *never* so when someone is learning the language.

Comment: But that's what he asked.

Comment: @user3344003 the original poster is obviously a beginner. And when he asks "Can we do X", he obviously means "Can we do X and have the program still do something useful". Just answering in a "technically correct way" on the "Can we do X" part, while ignoring the "..while still doing something useful"-part, is pure evil.

Comment: Without an explanation of what he is trying to do at a global level, it is impossible to tell him what to do in a software engineering way. He's complaining about assigning one pointer type to another. Why? I' don't now? That's our shortstop.

Comment: If you lack information to come up with a useful answer, you should either not answer, or ask for more info. If you told your mechanic: "My brake warning light is lighting up, can you make it go away", would you A) Have your mechanic remove the light, B) Have the mechanic ask if you want your brakes fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the usage of pointers is not recommended. however, you can take a look at this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    int a[2][2] = {{1,2},{3,4}};
    int *ptr1=a[0];
    int *ptr2=&a[0][0];
    int **ptr3=&ptr1;
    int **ptr4=&ptr2;

    std::cout << "the source variable:  " << a[0][0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "pointer to array:  " << ptr1[0] << ", " << ptr1[1] <<
                                  ", " << ptr1[2] << ", " << ptr1[3] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "pointer to one element:  " << *ptr2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "pointer to pointer:  " << **ptr3 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "pointer to pointer:  " << **ptr4 << std::endl << std::endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Some good explanations are available at [pointers-to-pointers](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/6-14-pointers-to-pointers/) and [pointers-and-arrays](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/6-8-pointers-and-arrays/)

Note: Generally, using pointers is not recommended as it might cause difficulties when debugging such as memory leak or invalid memory access!
As a result, smart pointers are invented to prevent possible consequences of normal pointers. You can take a look at [std::shared_ptr](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/15-6-stdshared_ptr/).

Comment: I'm not sure you understand just how potentially dangerous this is about to be for the OP. If they walk away thinking "this is how I can access a *full* native array of arrays using a pointer-to-pointer", they're in for a world of hurt on all elements except those of the base array's most-inferior dimension. Knowledge is good, but a *little* knowledge can be a very dangerous thing.